# Assigning a Node to an xsl:variable using depending on a test

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm totally unfamiliar with xslt, so please excuse me if this is a daft question.
I need to declare a variable and point it at one of 2 possible nodes in the xml, depending on which of them actually exists. I'm trying the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="DealNode">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/AllResponse/Deals/Deal"><xsl:copy-of select="/AllResponse/Deals/Deal"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="/AllResponse/BookDeals/BookDeal"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

This appears to work, in that DealNode does appear to be what I expect. However, if I now do:

```
<xsl:variable name="TradeNode" select="$DealNode/Trades/Trade"/>
```

TradeNode remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

Sample xml:

```
<AllResponse>
    <Deals>
        <Deal>
            <Trades>
                <Trade>
                </Trade>
            </Trades>
        </Deal>
    </Deals>
</AllResponse>
```

Comment: Are you working in XSLT 1 or 2?

Comment: Sorry, should have said that its xslt 1..

Comment: @StevieG: It might be useful to notice that the currently accepted answer is rather problematic. For more information, please, read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to define the variable is as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="DealNode" select="(/AllResponse/Deals/Deal | /AllResponse/BookDeals/BookDeal)[1]"/>
```

That forms the union of both selected node-sets and takes the first node in that union so that way if the first expression select a node that node is taken, if the first expression does not select anything then the first node selected by the second expression is taken.

Comment: Sorry, but this would work on a sequence -- the union of two *node-sets* is a new node-set, where the nodes (by definition) are in document order. Therefore, `($ns1|$ns2)[1]` in the general case doesn't select the first node of `$ns1` -- instead this selects the first node (in document order) of the union of the two nodesets -- this may be a node that belongs to `$ns` or a node that belongs to `$ns2`. Please, correct.

Comment: -1, because the answer contains non-true statement and in general an incorrect solution that could confuse and mislead learners of XPath.

Answer (score 4):

**The currently-accepted answer has a serious problem. If its XPath expression is evaluated against the following XML document**:

```
<AllResponse>
    <BookDeals>
        <BookDeal>
            <Trades>
                <Trade>
                </Trade>
            </Trades>
        </BookDeal>
    </BookDeals>
    <Deals>
        <Deal>
            <Trades>
                <Trade>
                </Trade>
            </Trades>
        </Deal>
    </Deals>
</AllResponse>
```

**then, contrary to the claims in the answer, the provided XPath expression**:

```
(/AllResponse/Deals/Deal | /AllResponse/BookDeals/BookDeal)[1]
```

**doesn't select the first argument of the union, but exactly the opposite** (the 2nd argument).

The reason for this is that the result of the union operation is always sorted by the document order of its nodes -- in other words, a node-set is a set and not a sequence.

**Here is a correct solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vDealNode" select=
      "/*/Deals/Deal | /*[not(Deals/Deal)]/BookDeals/BookDeal"/>
      
     <xsl:copy-of select="$vDealNode"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the above XML document, the wanted, correct result (the node that is the first argument of the union operator) is selected** and the result of this selection is output:

```
<Deal>
   <Trades>
      <Trade/>
   </Trades>
</Deal>
```

**Explanation**: The correct general expression to use when we want to select `$ns1` when a condition `$cond` is `true()` and to select `$ns2` when `$cond` is false, is:

```
$ns1[$cond] | $ns2[not($cond)]
```

In our concrete case:

`$ns1` is `/*/Deals/Deal`,

`$ns2` is `/*/BookDeals/BookDeal`

and

`$cond` is `boolean(/*/Deals/Deal)`

**Substituting these in the general expression above, and shortening**:

`/*/Deals/Deal[/*/Deals/Deal]`

to:

`/*/Deals/Deal`

**we arrive at the expression used in this answer**:

```
/*/Deals/Deal | /*[not(Deals/Deal)]/BookDeals/BookDeal
```

Comment: I found this answer worked for me (using XSLT 1.0) whereas the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT1 doesn't fully support result-tree fragments.  To do what you are attempting requires `exsl:node-set()`.

Also, even in XSLT2, the correct XPath is `$DealNode/Deal/Trades/Trade`